# Slight one time rubbing noise in the rear of car

Tags: ford, noise, expedition, grinding

When I start driving my Ford Expedition 2013,I hear a one time slight rubbing/ grinding noise seemingly from the rear  when the vehicle reaches 20 km/h. Its not a continuous noise.Please help. Mechanics refuse to declare it as wheel bearing noise.
One of the mechanics advised me to get ATF examined and replaced if necessary. I did so. It was a mess.My transmission mechanic just gave it it a try by changing the ATF and transmission filter.He says my transmission is in superb condition. I just had it computer tested.All is fine.The rubbing click is too low to be heard by some of the mechanics during a test drive.One more thing. It happened every time when I turned my engine off and started it again.I never hear it during the rest of the drive above 20 km/h.Gear shift is smooth.
Thanks to those who responded. I am living in Saudi Arabia.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! They are probably refusing to call it a wheel bearing because a wheel bearing would be a constant noise. While I'm sure something is going on, I'm afraid your question doesn't have enough detail in it for us to attempt to answer it. If you could edit the question with more detail about what is going on, we might be able to help.

Comment: Parking brake hanging on?

Comment: Experiment and record occurence of noise. What if you goto 30 then 10 then 20? What if you sway left right when at 20 with noise? Does gear change happen at 20? Hear it at bumps?  If you start car let idle for while stop, then restart and drive does it happen? Going to have to try and narrow down details of when and when not with this tricky noise

Answer (score 0):

If your car makes noise when accelerating, it can be a problem like a worn-out clutch disc or wheel bearing. Does this happen when you are turning or is there a wheezing sound also?

Comment: I will be mindful while turning to detect the sound now.

Comment: great! just make sure to drive safe and slowly for a bit and be attentive for any new sounds